# iOS upload image file NSData and get POST PHP variables

Tags: ios, post, upload

I been avoiding the ASIFormDataRequest a bit because it did not quite fit my needs and had too much code for my simple needs.

SO:

I found a few other pieces of code, yet none of which managed to transfer and vraiables or the image data over as the image doesn't show up and the response doesn'y show the vars.

Here is the code:

```
NSData * imageData = myImageData;

NSString *urlString = [[self getDBCGIFolder] stringByAppendingString:DATABASE_PATH_UPLOAD_PORTRAIT];

NSString *values = @"&accountID:";
values = [values stringByAppendingString:myAccountID];
values = [values stringByAppendingString:@"&shit:"];
values = [values stringByAppendingString:@"SHITE"];
NSData *valueData = [values dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSLog(urlString);

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:valueData]];


[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"--%@", returnString);
```

This code got me furthest with a solid reply string in XML that lets me check the arriving data in the PHP script, but no data seems to get there.

Anyone?

Comment: By 'no data seems to get there' do you mean 0 bytes in the request body or that the script can not parse it in the way you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to submit multipart form data, but in that code, you are appending both the string and image data without encoding them as separate values. Both ASIHTTPRequest and AFNetworking give you this functionality out of the box, so though it may seem more simple to roll your own, you'd be better served giving one of those a deeper look.